# Iceland - Visiting fjords from Reykjavík in 1 day

Tags: driving, iceland, fjords, reykjavik

We're travelling to Iceland early May this year. Our accommodation will be in Reykjavík, but we would like to see the fjords in the north as well (around Ísafjörður). According to Google Maps, it's more than 400 kms just to get there by car. We don't want to stay there for the night, thus we would have to drive 800+ kms that day.

How long does it usually take on the Icelandic roads? Do you think it's manageable and / or worth it? Are there any similar land features (= fjords) closer to Reykjavík?

Comment: If you want to go to Isafjörður, you should then take the plane :) this is less than an hour

Comment: @Megmoli Thanks! I checked the prices, unfortunately ~200 € / person wouldn't fit our budget.

Comment: Hvalfjörður, just over half an hour to the North of Rvk would be an option. I find it beautiful, but YMMV. Anyway, if you don't mind a hike, you can hike up the mountain to behold the highest waterfall in Iceland: Glymur. It's at about the deepest the fjord cuts into the land. And it's worth it every time. Hiked up there several times and love it each and every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No road in Iceland has a speed limit higher than 90kph, so at a minimum this would take you over 8 hours just in driving (and in practice you can't go even that speed everywhere, even in good weather). In fact, Google thinks it is [approximately a 11.5 hour round trip](http://goo.gl/maps/0jsRl). So I would say your visit is likely to feel quite rushed and you'll be driving for a very long time, which of course could be potentially dangerous given the risk of tiredness. Nevertheless, the advantage of travelling in May is that [the daylight hours are extremely long](http://www.enjoyiceland.is/Iceland_Information/Practical_information/Time_and_daylight_hours/).

Iceland has quite a mature internal air network. You may want to check that out to see if it can help you with your journey.